# Question about Mutual Information

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, fake-proofs, entropy

I am learning about mutual information, and am confused about one of the definitions.  Mutual information is defined as 
$ I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X | Y) $

where,

$$ H(X) = \sum_{x} p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} ,$$

and similarly,

$$ H(X|Y) = \sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \frac{1}{p(x|y)} $$

where $H(X)$ is concerned we can then say that,

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_x p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} 
&= \sum_x \left( (p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)}) \sum_y p(y|x) \right) 
\\ &= \sum_{x,y} p(x)p(y|x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} =
\\ &= \sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} 
\end{align*}
$$

because $ \sum \limits_y p(y|x) = 1 $ for any $x$.

I believe this is how the derivation is supposed to go, and combined with $H(X|Y)$ eventually leads to the canonical equation,

$$\sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)} .$$

But it seems to me that it is equally true to say that,

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x} p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} 
&= \sum_{x} \left\{ ( p(x) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} ) \sum_{y} p(y) \right\} 
\\ &= \sum_{x,y} p(x)p(y) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} 
\end{align*}
$$

because we also have $ \sum_{y} p(y) = 1 $ by definition.

The problem I'm having is that this latter version implies that,

$$\sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} = \sum_{x,y} p(x)p(y) \log \frac{1}{p(x)} $$

which implies that $ p(x,y) = p(x)p(y) $ which also implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  I know this last conclusion is false, because it means there would never be any mutual information and thus that this metric would be pointless, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  It would be great to have someone point out the mistake I am making in the latter case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula $$\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log \frac{1}{p(x)} = \sum_{x,y}p(x)p(y)\log \frac{1}{p(x)}$$ is indeed correct, since you can always average out $y$ because $p(x)$ does obviously not depend on $y$. Howvever, it *does not imply* that $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$  ($2 -2 = 1 -1 = 0$, but not $1=2$).

Comment: Oh geeez... I'm not sure whether to be happy or feel even more retarded.  In any case thanks a bunch for pointing out what should have been obvious.  I've marked your answer as correct, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote you.

Comment: I so know the feeling :). In any case, you're welcome. Happy to be of help.